# Preg_match somehow not finding part of string

Tags: php, preg-match

I am having a problem with preg_match in that it is not returning anything. While according to: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?=35ls9

It should be functioning properly.

This is my current code:

```
$string == <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/...." data-widget-id="352777062139922223">....</a>...
```

its simply the embed code twitter throws out when creating a widget. Was also included in the example.

```
$string = get_field('twitter_feed');  //contains the string.
preg_match('/data-widget-id="([0-9]*)"/', $string, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Its probably something really simple that i am missing. Hopefully somebody is able to help me with this problem.

edit: added the sample string.

Comment: Can you provide a sample section or an example of what `$string` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it with the following string. I did, and it works fine:

```
$string = 'data-widget-id="352777062139922223"';
```

Make sure that `get_field` is returning a string in that form.

Comment: That indeed works when i try it.. means get_field somehow modifies what is returned in some way or form.

Comment: Try echoing the result from get_field to see what you get.

Comment: This is the output according to the source:  
        `&lt;a class=&quot;twitter-timeline&quot; href=&quot;https://twitter.com/schippernick&quot; data-widget-id=&quot;352777062139965443&quot;&gt;Tweets by @schippernick&lt;/a&gt;<br />
&lt;script&gt;!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?&#039;http&#039;:&#039;https&#039;;if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+&quot;://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js&quot;;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,&quot;script&quot;,&quot;twitter-wjs&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;<br />`

Comment: @Schippie Looks like all special characters have been changed into their HTML entity codes, including `"` (which is now `&quot;`).

Comment: Yup that was it thank you very much this is the final regex code: `preg_match('/data-widget-id=&quot;([0-9]*)&quot;/', $string, $match);`